# n-point hull of a set of points

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I ran into the following, deceptively simple problem, and I was wondering if there is a well-known algorithmic solution to it:

Given a set of points $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (or $\mathbb{R}^2$, for simplicity), find a $n$-sided polygon, such that

- all points in $S$ are inside the polygon
- the area of the resulting polygon is minimal.

Any references or hints towards a solution are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific running time requirement?

Comment: Is $n$ a parameter/part of the input? If I can have any number of sides I want, the answer is trivial: plot a line from point to point and thicken it slightly to make a very long, thin polygon of as close to zero area as you want.

Comment: I guess you mean that the "resulting polygon" should also be convex. If yes then please add that into your problem formulation